# How to apply armature/rig transformation to the mesh/shape key?

Tags: modeling, rigging

So I added a jaw bone thinking it would help me to model/give some consistency to Key 3 Visemes/shape keys but now I don't know how to proceed from here:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Instead of adding 'Solved' to the title, you can 'accept' an existing answer (even your own) and this will mark it as solved. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Im aware of that, its just that there is 2 days... timeout before one can accept their own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind...

[image]

Just after applying it, it will disappear, but no worries, All vertex groups are still there, just Add_Modifier.Deform.Armature And set Armature as the "Object"